# Redirecting linux cout to a variable and the screen in a script

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cout

I am currently trying to make a script file that runs multiple other script files on a server. I would like to display the output of these script to the screen IN ADDITION to passing it into grep so I can do error testing. currently I have written this:

```
    status=$(SOMEPROCESS | grep -i "SOMEPROCESS started completed correctly")
```

I do further error handling below this using the variable status, so I would like to display SOMEPROCESS's output to the screen for error reference. This is a read only server and I can not save the output to a log file.

Comment: `someprocess | tee -a /dev/stdout | grep -i "..."`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `tee` command. It will be slightly fiddly, since tee outputs to a file handle. However you could create a file descriptor using `pipe`.

Or (simpler) for your use case.

Start the script without grep and pipe it through tee `SOMEPROCESS | tee /my/safely/generated/filename`. Then use `tail -f /my/safely/generated/filename | grep -i "my grep pattern` separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use process substituion together with `tee`:

```
SOMEPROCESS | tee >(grep ...)
```

This will use an anonymous pipe and pass `/dev/fd/...` as file name to `tee` (or a named pipe on platforms that don't support `/dev/fd/...`).

Because `SOMEPROCESS` is likely to buffer its output when not talking to a terminal, you might see significant lag in screen output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understood your question exactly.

I think you want to get the output of `SOMEPROCESS`, test it, print it out when there are errors. If it is, I think the code bellow may help you:

```
s=$(SOMEPROCESS)
grep -q 'SOMEPROCESS started completed correctly' <<< $s
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];then
    # specified string not found in the output, it means SOMEPROCESS started failed
    echo $s
fi
```

But in this code, it will store the all output in the memory, if the output is big enough, there will be a OOM risk.